# Better "Randomization" with Simplexml and PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a 'thought' function for a game i'm working on -- it pulls random strings from an XML file, combines them and makes them 'funny'. However, i'm running into a small issue in that the same couple of items keep getting selected each time.

The two functions I am using are

```
       function randRoller($number)
   {
     mt_srand((microtime()*time())/3.145);
     $x = [];
     for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
     {
        #$x = mt_rand(0,$number);
     }
     return mt_rand(0,$number);
   }
/* RETRIEVE ALL RELEVANT DATA FROM THE XML FILE */
   function retrieveFromXML($node)
   {
   $node = strtolower($node);
    $output = [];
    $n = substr($node,0,4);
    #echo $node;
    foreach($this->xml->$node->$n as $data)
    {
     $output[] = $data->attributes();
    }
    $count = count($output)-1;

    $number = $this->randRoller($count);
     return $output[$number];
    }
```

Granted, the "randRoller" function is sorta defunct now because the orginal version I had (Which 'rolled' ten numbers from the count, and then selected the one which got the most number of dice) didn't work as planned.

I've tried everything i can think of to get better results && have googled my brains out to fix it. but still am getting the same repetitive results.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `mt_srand()` unless you know what you are doing, since it is called automatically. See the note on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php:

> **Note**: There is no need to seed the random number generator with srand() or mt_srand() as this is done automatically.

Remove (all) the `mt_srand()` call(s).